# How to get xhtml2pdf working on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xhtml2pdf

I have been trying to figure out how to get XHTML2PDF working on GAE. I have managed to download the packages and dependencies and add them to my project folder. But I keep getting errors of missing modules. I have tried downloading different versions and the recommended versions. Can anyone please guide me in the right direction. It has passed my mind that this might be due to `app.yaml` but I really don't know, nor do I know how to set this up.

So what I have done:

I have downloaded [xhtml2pdf 0.0.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xhtml2pdf), the requirements are:

> Reportlab Toolkit 2.2+
>
> html5lib 0.11.1+
>
> pyPdf 1.11+ (optional)

I have then downloaded the following dependencies, couldn't find exact versions.  *(But I am guessing the '+' sign means anything above)*:

> [reportlab 3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab/3.0)
>
> [html5lib 0.999](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib/0.999)
>
> [pyPdf 1.13](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf/1.13)

I have copied the following folders into my project root directory:

> xhtml2pdf-0.0.5.tar.gz \ dist \ xhtml2pdf-0.0.5.tar \ xhtml2pdf-0.0.5 \ **xhtml2pdf**
>
> reportlab-3.0.tar.gz \ reportlab-3.0.tar \ reportlab-3.0 \ src \ **reportlab**
>
> html5lib-0.999.tar.gz \ dist \ html5lib-0.999.tar \ html5lib-0.999 \ **html5lib**
>
> pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz \ pyPdf-1.13.tar \ pyPdf-1.13 \ **pyPdf**

Here's the punchline.. as soon as I add the line **'from xhtml2pdf import pisa'** my app stops working.  If it is in **localhost** i get a blank screen but if I upload it using the GAE SDK then I get error's of missing modules - always different messages depending on the configuration of dependency versions I use.

Please keep in mind that I am new to GAE, Python and programming in general.

Comment: Please provide the code you tested and errors you get, it would be easier to help you

Comment: @radia: So that is what I have done. Any suggestions on what I should be looking into? As I said as soon as I add 'from xhtml2pdf import pisa' my app stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I realise now that XHTML2PDF aint gonna work.  Still don't know why, but have decided to use ReportLab on its own instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to run a recent version of xhtml2pdf on GAE.

I copied the recent versions of html2pdf/reportlab and it's dependencies to the root of the application, i had also to tweak/patch reportlab in one line

Code can be found here: https://github.com/danimajo/pineapple_pdf

Demo is here: http://flaskpineapple.appspot.com/pdf/